# Razor Pages 3.1 configuration injection into class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Injection of configuration does not work within simple class (not inherited from `PageModel`) where I keep my code

Despite this code:

```
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

public MyClass(IConfiguration configuration){
_configuration = configuration;
}
```

class once initialised as an object always asks for parameter `configuration`, which shall be injected by framework. That is how it works for Razor Pages - classes inherited from `PageModel`.

All configuration within `Program.cs` and `Startup.cs` are standard as where created by Visual Studio. I use Visual Studio 16.4.5 and ASP.NET Core 3.1.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you aren't using a form of strongly typed configuration?

Comment: Just playing with and learning RazorPages, need to load one string (db connection) from `appsettings.json`. Once same code is put into RazorPage, not a pure class, all works fine.

Comment: As with any service type, so long as `IConfiguration` is setup in your service provider, it should be returned by `.GetService()`, and provided to any constructor of other configured services.

Comment: Will provide more code tomorrow, as I do not understand that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inject `IConfiguration` in custom class , you can register your class into DI so that it helps resovle dependency :

```
services.AddTransient<CustomClass>();
```

Then define instance in where you want to use custom class , for example , in index page :

```
private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
private CustomClass _myClass;
public PrivacyModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, CustomClass myClass)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _myClass = myClass;
}

public void OnGet()
{
    var connectString=   _myClass.getConnectString();
}
```

Your class :

```
public class CustomClass
{
    private IConfiguration _configuration;

    public CustomClass(IConfiguration configuration) {
        _configuration = configuration;

    }

    public string getConnectString() {

        return  _configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"); ;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, however you have presented an option to inject CustomClass into RazorPage. Just for learning purposes, I would like to execute method of custom class by `CustomClass CustomClassObject = new CustomClass();string conn = CustomClassObject.getConnectString();`, however CustomClass has no access to `IConfiguration`, which is not injected hence `new CustomClass()` asks for a parameter.

Comment: In other words as an generalisation, I looking for a way to inject `IConfiguration` directly into `CustomClass` to read configuration in there, same as it can be done from Razor Page. This way, I don't need to worry about anything from Razor Page, as everything will be encapsulated in `CustomClass`

Comment: Understood eventually the whole concept. Accepting as an solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try using the `[inject]` attribute like so:

```
    [Inject]
    private IConfiguration Config { get; set; }
```

This should inject your IConfiguration into a property in your class.